# SQL Server Group By and Left Outer Join Custom result set

Tags: sql, join, group-by, having

I have two tables RDC and Cons_Status, rdc has a unique column in it RDC_ConsNO. And against this Consignment Number, there could be multiple records in Cons_Status table as depicted in the image attached. I want to write a query in which I get only one record joined to the status with maximum sts_id. I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT STS_ID,RDC_CONSNO,STS_STATUS , RDC_DATE,RDC_CUSTOMER,DEST_NAME FROM RDC LEFT OUTER JOIN CONS_STATUS ON RDC_CONSNO=STS_CONSNO
INNER JOIN DESTINATION ON DEST_ID=RDC_DESTINATION WHERE RDC_CONSNO='HD88300'
ORDER BY STS_ID
```

Database diagram for the tables

[image]

Comment: Dont show images. Links [are dead sometime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), we also can't use them to create sample data.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please have a look now.

Comment: I don't understand, you have just added even more images. If you would copy/paste sample data we would have both, data and schema in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) by using it's ["Text to DDL"](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/sql-fiddles-text-to-ddl-option) capability.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added the query and thought you need to know table structure to understand the query better, if you need table structure in query form, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to prefix your columns

```
SELECT ?? FROM RDC
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CONS_STATUS
WHERE RDC.RDC_CONSNO = STS_CONSNO
ORDER BY sts_id DESC
) a
INNER JOIN DESTINATION d
ON d.DEST_ID=RDC.RDC_DESTINATION 
WHERE RDC.RDC_CONSNO='HD88300'
ORDER BY a.STS_ID
```

Comment: @t-clause.dk Thanks cross apply does work but it eliminates the usage of Left outer join. If there are no associated record in cons_status table, it simply does not return anything.

Comment: @MegaMind it is outer apply now